# Handle inputs in NativeActivity

Tags: c++, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface, native-activity

I have a Native Activity android project with Android studio, I added the `ANativeActivity_onCreate`. now I wanna handle inputs, I found `callbacks` in the activity pointer but I can't find a good tutorial to know how to handle them.

In Eclipse there is a `android_main` void where I can make a loop and listen to user inputs, but in android studio I can't use `android_main` but only `ANativeActivity_onCreate`.

Comment: "in android studio I can't use android_main" why not?